# Cargar Datos de Dataframe a Tabla SQL Server

Tags: python

Estoy haciendo un pequeño desarrollo que carga la información de un *dataframe* llamado `df_final` a una tabla (Raw_Data) dentro de una base de datos SQL Server. No tengo problemas en la generación del dataframe ni en la conexion a la base de datos, el problema está cuando trato de cargar la información del DF a la tabla; estoy usando el siguiente código:

```
# Establecer la conexión con la base de datos SQL Server
conn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server};Server=SERVER;Database=DATA;Trusted_Connection=yes")
cursor = conn.cursor()

# Nombre de la tabla en SQL Server
table_name = "Raw_Data"

# Generar la sentencia SQL INSERT
columns = df_final.columns.tolist()
columns_str = ', '.join(columns)
placeholders = ', '.join(['?' for _ in range(len(columns))])
insert_query = f"INSERT INTO {table_name} ({columns_str}) VALUES ({placeholders});"

# Cargar los datos en la tabla
cursor.fast_executemany = True
cursor.executemany(insert_query, df_final.values.tolist())
conn.commit()

# Cerrar la conexión con la base de datos
conn.close()
```

pero aparece este error al ejecutarlo:     cursor.executemany(insert_query, df_final.values.tolist())

```
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'Id'. (102) (SQLExecute); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")
```

Si este código funcionara, deberia cargar la totalidad de los datos del DF a la tabla, pero realmente lo que necesito es que se verifique la condición de la tabla, si está vacía cargar la totalidad de datos del df, pero si tiene datos se debe cargar solo los datos que estén en el df pero que no este en la tabla y sobre escribir los comunes, validando la columna Period ID, por ejemplo, si en la tabla están los periodos M_1, M_2, M_3 y en el df estan los periodo M_2, M_4, M_5, entonces se debe agregar los datos de los periodos M_4, M_5, borrar en la tabla M_2 y sobre escribir con los datos del DF.

Estas son las columnas del df_final :

```
'Country Id', 'Period ID', 'Store ID SMS', 'Store ID CDAR', 'Audit Instruction ID',
'Store Status', 'Actual Visit Date', 'Category ID', 'Category Name', 'Module ID',
'Module Name', 'Product ID', 'Bar Code', 'Product Description', 'Auditor ID',
'Resource Name', 'Supervisor ID', 'Supervisor Name', 'Cluster ID', 'Plan Id',
'Plan Name', 'Cluster Name', '(CEP) Transferencia de Items', '(EOP) Stock Omitido',
'[Compras Indirectas]', '[Total Ajustes]', '[Total Compras]', '[Total Inventario]',
'[Total Ventas]', 'Accesibilidad', 'Compras Fabricante', 'Compras Mayorista',
'Credito', 'Exhibición Especial/Lugar Preponderante', 'Fab (CE) Compra Estimada',
'Fab (NOP) Factura Omitida', 'Fab (SD) Sin Documento', 'Inventario Area de ventas',
'Inventario Bodega', 'Inventario Frio', 'Material POP (Publicidad)',
'May (CE) Compra Estimada', 'May (NOP) Factura Omitida', 'May (SD) Sin Documento',
'Oferta del fabricante', 'Precio regular', 'Presencia', 'Visibilidad'
```

y estas son las columnas de la tabla:

```
[Country Id] INT, [Period ID] NVARCHAR(10), [Store ID SMS] INT, [Store ID CDAR] INT,[Audit Instruction ID] INT, [Store Status] VARCHAR(50), [Actual Visit Date] DATE, [Category ID] INT, [Category Name] VARCHAR(100), [Module ID] INT, [Module Name] VARCHAR(100), [Product ID] INT, [Bar Code] BIGINT, [Product Description] VARCHAR(255), [Auditor ID] INT, [Resource Name] VARCHAR(100), [Supervisor ID] INT, [Supervisor Name] VARCHAR(100), [Cluster ID] INT,
[Plan Id] INT, [Plan Name] VARCHAR(100), [Cluster Name] VARCHAR(100), [CEP Transferencia de Items] INT, [EOP Stock Omitido] INT, [Compras Indirectas] INT, [Total Ajustes] FLOAT, [Total Compras] INT, [Total Inventario] INT, [Total Ventas] INT, [Accesibilidad] INT, [Compras Fabricante] INT, [Compras Mayorista] INT, [Credito] INT, [Exhibición Especial/Lugar Preponderante] INT, [Fab (CE) Compra Estimada] INT, [Fab (NOP) Factura Omitida] INT, [Fab (SD) Sin Documento] INT, [Inventario Area de ventas] INT, [Inventario Bodega] INT, [Inventario Frio] INT, [Material POP (Publicidad)] INT, [May (CE) Compra Estimada] INT,
[May (NOP) Factura Omitida] INT, [May (SD) Sin Documento] INT, [Oferta del fabricante] INT,
[Precio regular] FLOAT, [Presencia] INT, [Visibilidad] INT
```

Comment: Esta pregunta en realidad contiene varias. Escribí una respuesta para la pregunta principal. Por el funcionamiento del sitio, la regla es una pregunta por pregunta. Sería mejor que escribas preguntas nuevas para cada una de tus dudas o problemas. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La sentencia SQL es inválida. Esto se debe a que hay columnas cuyo nombre tiene espacios.

Mira el resultado de este pequeño fragmento que replica parte de tu código:

```
columns = ['Country Id', 'Period ID', 'Store ID SMS']

table_name = "miTabla"
columns_str = ', '.join(columns)
placeholders = ', '.join(['?' for _ in range(len(columns))])

insert_query = f"insert into {table_name} ({columns_str}) values ({placeholders});"
print(insert_query)
```

Produce la salida:

```sql
insert into miTabla (Country Id, Period ID, Store ID SMS) values (?, ?, ?);
```

Esta es una sentencia SQL inválida que producirá el error:

```
Incorrect syntax near 'Id'
```

La solución es encerrar todos los identificadores que puedan contener espacios entre corchetes, incluso el nombre de la tabla, por ejemplo, con este cambio:

```
table_name = "[" + table_name + "]"
columns_str = ', '.join("[" + col + "]" for col in columns)
```

Ya produce el SQL válido:

```sql
insert into [miTabla] ([Country Id], [Period ID], [Store ID SMS]) values (?, ?, ?);
```

**edición**:

Justo ahora que edité la pregunta me dí cuenta que el *dataframe* contiene columnas que ya tienen corchetes. En ese caso, y suponiendo que los nombres de las columnas en SQL Server no los tienen, no haría falta añadirlos, eso podrías lograrlo simplemente condicionando al primer caracter del nombre de la columna.

```
columns_str = ', '.join("[" + col + "]" if col[0] != "[" else col for col in columns)
```

Ya te toca a tí ver que tan lejos tiene que llegar esto... si tienes columnas que tienen el primer corchete pero no el último, o que tienen el último pero no el primero, por ejemplo, tocaría adaptar aún más el código.

Igual si tienes columnas en la tabla que no se llaman igual que en el *dataframe*. De mi parte, creo que te he dado el análisis del problema, una manera de validarlo y las herramientas para poder hacer el trabajo.